# JavaScript Code Appears Well Formatted, Except for, "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :"

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax-error, unexpected-token

Goodmorning folks!

I've been testing my JavaScript code via the Google Chrome developer console, and fixed all of the errors, except one that says,**"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :"** I found similar questions on Stack Overflow, but my situation is different. In addition, usually when the console lists the error, it would have provide a link to view the error, which would be underlined in red. However, this time the console lists the error, but doesn't underline, in red, the wrong part of the code.

[image: Screen-shot of Google Chrome Developer Console Displaying Error]

To me everything looks formatted correctly, and all my double colons look correctly placed. Are you able to help? Thanks in advance!

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

//when search is clicked run code
$(search).on('Click'(function(){

//gets search input
var searchTerm= $("#searchTerm").val();

//API url with searchTerm
var url="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=query&titles=Main%20Page&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=jsonfm";

//create an AJAX call within .on("Click") function
$.ajax({})
    //We intend to do a GET call (because we are retrieving data from the server)
    type: "GET"
    url: url,
    //code will be paused while other code waiting for this to finish
    Async: false,
    dataType: json,
    Success: function(data){ 
    //How will you test for success of json call function
    console.log()data;  
},

//Do something when its a function and do something else when it's a failure
Error: function(errorMessage){
    //Console out a warning that says something like "error" alert
    alert("Error"); 
}


}); //search

});//document ready
```

Comment: Line numbers in the error will help you debug it in future.

Comment: @MorganLane, line numbers? I have that in my text-editor....

Comment: `$(search).on('Click'(function(){` <-- that ain't right

Comment: and `console.log()data;` ain't right....

Comment: @epascarello, how are these not right? Can you explain?

Comment: and missing comma....  so far 3 things wrong with "well formatted code"

Comment: you can not see the issue with those?

Comment: @epascarello, can't the click function be written as `$('#search').click(function(){
}

or as

`$(search).on('Click'(function(){
}
`
...........???

Comment: yes, but you can also use on, if you do it the right way. It has two issues. Case matters and it is missing a comma.  Other one is also pretty obvious. Any good linter would pick these up. Look at the examples for on.... http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: @epascarello, ok, I see the case issue, but where is the missing comma? I also just fixed the `console.log(data)` issue.....it should be `console.log (data)`....And how come the console isn't showing all these errors that you've pointed out? That's weird to me....

Comment: The parser stops when it sees the error. Look at the link I posted to the jQuery docs for `on` and compare it to what you have.

Comment: and the Ajax line is wrong.... just noticed that... Properly indent your code and you can spot these issues. Use a linter like jshint http://jshint.com/ or eslint, jslint, etc.

Comment: @SudiptaKumarMaiti, I saw the error that @epascarello pointed out in AJAX.... and `console data`....I don't need the unpolite-ness of "please code properly", if people could all code properly, Stack Overflow would not exist!

Comment: @codebwoy Basically you really should learn to use your tools to help you spot your issues. Your code not being properly indented does not help. Integrate a linter into your IDE so it helps to enforce good practices.

Comment: @epascarello.....I agree....I'm also a JavaScript newbie, and have designed a couple successful web apps with JavaScript, but due to always being in a rush, I don't always retain what I learn well lol....and where can I learn how to integrate a linter into my IDE?...I use a Sublime text-editor....infact, is Sublime an IDE?

Answer (score 3):

You are missing `,` after `type: "GET"`

Comment: I just fixed that and it still is showing “Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :”